# PayPal: receive copy of email sent to user when refund is issued

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to either configure PayPal or retrieve via API a copy of the email sent to users when a refund is issued?

Answer (score 0):

I was scouring around however I was unable to find anything to support what you're asking. So this would be  no sir.